# integrate dotnetnuke module in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

i have existing asp.net web application it includes membership and roles and admin section,etc.  Now i would like to integrate dotnetnuke journal module in my asp.net web application.

is it posible to integrate dotnetnuke module in my web app? i download dotnetnuke source and i compiled journal module.

can any one update me how to integrate dotnetnuke module in my web app..i don't want to switch   to dotnetnuke for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to utilize the APIs to access the journal from your custom application.

The module itself is dependent upon DNN and its context (users, pages, modules, etc) in order to function properly.

I am sure you could rip a lot of that out, but I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

> is it posible to integrate dotnetnuke module in my web app?

No.

Your only way to succeed in your quest would be to convert your ASP.NET application into the DotNetNuke application.  To do that, you're going to have to merge the authentication side of the two sites.  This shouldn't be impossible since DNN uses the ASP.NET authentication provider.

If you can merge the user database into a DotNetNuke installation properly, you're halfway there.  You could then use the DotNetNuke page management features to load your custom pages by linking to them directly, and gradually merge your existing application.

Otherwise, you have no hope of integrating the Journal module.  And you're up for hundreds if not thousands of hours of coding to try and replicate it.